# Methods all need to be indented one level in to indicate that they are methods of the class in python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm following the RSA algorithm from the Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)

I am using Python 3.3.0 and I'm trying to do RSA Encryption and I ran into two problems that I don't know how to do.

In the Encryptions class, my methods all need to be indented one level in to indicate that they are methods of the class and are not global functions.

When the main script asks for input at the end, if I just hit return, an exception is thrown that Python reached an unexpected EOF.

How can I do that ?

My code so far:

Modular.py

```
def _base_b_convert(n, b):
   if b < 1 or n < 0:
      raise ValueError("Invalid Argument")

   q = n
   a = []
   while q != 0:
      value = int(q % b)
      a.append(value)
      q =int(q / b)
   return a


def mod_exp(base, n, mod):
    if base < 0 or n < 0 or mod < 0:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Argument")
    a = (_base_b_convert(n, 2))
    x = 1
    pow = base % mod
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] == 1:
        x = (x * pow) % mod
    pow = pow**2 % mod
    return x
```

main.py

```
from encryptions import Encryptions

def main():
    enc = Encryptions()
    message = enc.encrypt(message)
    print(message)
    print()
    print("Decrypting message:")
    message = enc.decrypt(message)
    print(message)

    input("--Press any key to end--")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If yes, the `input` function does not what you think it does. It executes the given string as Python code. You want to use `raw_input` instead. Note that in Python 3, `input` does what `raw_input` does in Python 2.

Comment: @Agape: are you sure? Can you run `python -v` please.

Comment: What editor are you using to write this code? You need to use one that understands python, like Eclipse with PyDev installed.

Comment: if I put raw_input it gives me syntax error

Comment: I am actually using Pydev from Eclipse

Comment: I corrected the indent and the program runs correctly (using Python 3.3)

Comment: You don't need to implement modular exponentiation. You can use `pow(base, exponent, moduls)` which will be *a lot faster* than anything you can write in python.

Comment: @GregS: are you running Python 2 ? so you just corrected raw_input and works ? thanks

Comment: No, I'm running python 3.3

Comment: @GregS Still, this looks very much like a 2.x problem. My theory is that you are running on Windows and your .py file association runs python2.x. We can test this by adding _import sys; print(sys.version)_ to the top of your main module. At least you'd satisfy the hecklers!

Comment: @tdelaney: what aspect looks like a 2.x problem? I see nothing that points to 2.x.

Comment: @GregS In python 2.x, input() evaluates the text as python code. If you just hit return, it throws exactly the error you are getting. In python 3.x, input() reads the text and does no evaluation. Your script can't get the error you specify in python 3.x, but it will get exactly the error you specify in 2.x. So, I'm guessing you are running 2.x. Since you script doesn't have the usual linux preamble (#!/usr/bin/env python), I'm guessing you are running on windows. A typical python 2 v 3 issue in windows is which python is registered to run .py files.

Comment: @tdelaney: You need to be a little more careful to see who you are responding to. The OP is Agape, not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` in Python 2 is not what you think it is -- rather, it evaluates the string inputted as Python code, which is not what you want. Instead, use `raw_input`.

As for your indentation problem, that's just Python syntax. Nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is off. Sometimes you have 3 spaces, sometimes 4 and sometimes 5.

Another example is here

```
def mod_exp(base, n, mod):
    if base < 0 or n < 0 or mod < 0:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Argument")
    a = (_base_b_convert(n, 2))
    x = 1
    pow = base % mod
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] == 1:
        x = (x * pow) % mod
    pow = pow**2 % mod
    return x
```

it should look more like

```
def mod_exp(base, n, mod):
    if base < 0 or n < 0 or mod < 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Argument")
    a = (_base_b_convert(n, 2))
    x = 1
    pow = base % mod
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i] == 1:
            x = (x * pow) % mod
        pow = pow**2 % mod
    return x
```

Whenever you use if, while, for etc etc you need to indent one level.

(These problems maybe just because it badly copied into stackoverflow?)